# Java 8 stream: replace single item in streamed collection

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm somewhat new to working in Java 8, and am refactoring some older code with (what appears to be a good use case for) a stream operation.  The older code "works" but to my eyes it looks really inefficient.

The short version of my question is that I'm trying to find a single element of a List and replace it with an updated version of that same element (the key is the same, but properties have different values each time the code is called).

```
     try
     {
        List<Object> items = lookup(itemCache.getKey());
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
        {
           Object originalObject = items.get(i);
           if (originalObject.getPropValue() == newObject.getPropValue())
           {
              List<Object> newItems = new ArrayList<>(items);
              newItems.set(i, newObject);
              putIntoCache(newObject.getKey(), newItems);
              break;
           }
        }
     } 

     catch (Exception ex) { /*exception handling*/ }
```

Based on what I've read about streams thus far, it seems that I need to use a `.map()` or  `.filter()` to isolate the element I want to identify, but that also seems like operations occurring after either `filter` or `map` in the stream statement would be operating on either not the full List or on a List where every item is affected by the `.map()`.

It seems simple, but I am struggling to wrap my head around it. Because the initial lookup is a `List` itself, I was thinking the stream could replace all of this.  The `ArrayList<>()` appears in the original code, but ordering of the items isn't important so long as I am able to replace that item by its key.

If you choose to help, thank you.

Comment: Streams are not appropriate for _mutations_ of the source data.

Comment: Off topic, but if your cache implements `Map`, you might look into `Map.computeIfPresent(UnaryOperator<T>)`  instead of reading the `List` and writing it back to the cache.  The `computeIfAbsent` is thread safe in a ConcurrentHashMap, unlike the read-modify-write approach taken in these answers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
List<Object> newItems = items.stream()
    .map(o -> o.getPropValue() == newObject.getPropValue() ? newObject : o)
    .collect(toList());
putIntoCache(newObject.getKey(), newItems);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: Note the semantic differences. The original code replaces at most one occurrence and does nothing if no match was found, this code replaces all occurrences and will always create and publish a new list. Besides that, you can simplify it to: `items.stream().map(o -> o.getPropValue() == newObject.getPropValue()? newObject: o).collect(toList())`

Comment: if the contract is that `newItems` is a mutable copy of the data in the cache, you could use `newItems.replaceAll()` instead of the `Stream`.

Answer (score 4):

Streams are actually not particularly good for this snippet of code because it has an early `break` and simultaneously works with both indexes and elements.

You can build an equivalent statement like this:

```
List<Object> items = lookup(itemCache.getKey());
IntStream.range(0, items.size())
    .filter(i -> items.get(i).getPropValue() == newItem.getPropValue())
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(i -> {
        List<Object> newItems = new ArrayList<>(items);
        newItems.set(i, newObject);
        putIntoCache(newObject.getKey(), newItems);
    });
```

Is that really better? In my opinion, not particularly. We aren't really using any of the stream features, just replacing control flow syntax with API.

If the exact behavior is less important, then there are possibly better examples, like Jean's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function you want to apply is "replace the *first* element that matches the prop value". The *first* part (and break statement) are non-trivial (as you depend on all entries processed before that). In other words, it implies that your function depends on some additional state, so the domain can be expressed as `boolean * String`, where boolean tells you whether the replacement had been done. You can see it starts to get ugly.

If you are okay with replacing *all* matching values, then Jean Logeart's answer seems okay.